# Prevent line-break of span element

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span>` element which I want to display without any line break. How can I do that?

Comment: .word {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

Comment: This "duplicate" question is currently ranking higher on Google than its "original" counterpart. Somebody call the Stack Exchange Police.

Comment: I fell on this one that do not describe correctly the problem I had, because I try to prevent break-line on a list of `span`s, but allow the span to go on the line. The answer of @AliNajafZadeh put me on track, and a series of `<span class="unbreakable">` in a `<p>` with the `.unbreakable { display: inline-block;}` does the trick.
Thank you @AliNajafZadeh.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

Put this in your CSS:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Get more information here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space

`white-space`

The `white-space` property declares how white space inside the element is handled.

**Values**

`normal`
This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space, and break lines as necessary to fill line boxes.

`pre`
This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at newlines in the source, or at occurrences of "\A" in generated content.

**`nowrap`**
This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.

`pre-wrap`
This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are broken at newlines in the source, at occurrences of "\A" in generated content, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

`pre-line`
This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space. Lines are broken at newlines in the source, at occurrences of "\A" in generated content, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

`inherit`
Takes the same specified value as the property for the element's parent.

Comment: Also nice to add some more documentation here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space

Comment: For case when you have many spans inside of div and you want to achive single-line span but not single line div, you have to add to span also display: inline-block;. Hope it will help for somebody.

Answer (score 29):

If you only need to prevent line-breaks on space characters, you can use `&nbsp;` entities between words:

```
No&nbsp;line&nbsp;break
```

instead of

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">No line break</span>
```

Answer (score 19):

`white-space: nowrap` is the correct solution but it will prevent any break in a line. If you only want to prevent line breaks between two elements it gets a bit more complicated:

```
<p>
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
</p>
```

To prevent breaks between the spans but to allow breaks between "Some" and "text" can be done by:

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

That's good enough for Firefox. In Chrome you additionally need to replace the whitespace between the spans with an `&nbsp;`. (Removing the whitespace doesn't work.)

Answer (score -5):

**With Bootstrap 4 Class:**

```
text-nowrap
```

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow