# Preventing line break after <span style="display:inline-block">

Tags: html, css

In `<span>` elements in HTML narrative flow, in order to expand the area on which clicks are detected (some of the spans have content of only one character), I am adding padding (offsetting it with a negative margin) in  a class defined as

```
.expand-click-area {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:-5px;
    position:relative;
}
```

This works fine in terms of the clicking behavior. The problem is that Chrome 19 will sometimes line break between the span and the following comma in a case such as the following:

```
<span class="expand-click-area">this is span text</span>,
```

Any thoughts on how to prevent this? Essentially, I would like breaking behavior equivalent to that when the `<span>` is not there at all, or does not have `display:inline-block`.

This behavior does not seem to appear in IE10. See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/58XdJ/1/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent line-break of span element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300760/prevent-line-break-of-span-element)

Comment: For some reason, when I put my spanned text in a `<p>`, it no longer breaks the line. It's in a `<div>`, and I understand that both `<div>`s and `<p>`s are block-level, so it makes no sense. Maybe because my div is a flex box?

Answer (score 8):

Try wrapping the entire non-breakable text into the `<nobr>` tag.

Comment: That works, as does the CSS equivalent `<span style="white-space:nowrap">`.

Comment: I use `<nobr> </nobr>` for use with Foundation 5. I sometimes need to shorten a description or title on smaller devices, so I do things like this:    `<span class="hide-for-small">Dominant </span>Color`, but obviously that will break. So instead I use:     `<nobr><span class="hide-for-small">Dominant </span>Color</nobr>`. This is one really good reason I use it and it also means I don't have to write any css.

Comment: The `<nobr>` tag has been deprecated and is now obsolete:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody faces this problem and none of the above solved solutions the problem like in my case, i found that adding this to the span will solve it.

```
display: contents;
```

Hope this helps someone ;)