# How to prevent linebreak in blockquote(HTML)

Tags: html, css

Looks like the line breaks when there is a space and Length is long enough...
Here is my  code

```
<blockquote>
<p>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p>
<p>2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</p>
</blockquote>
```

[image]

Is there a way to prevent line breaking until the tag

happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent line-break of span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300760/prevent-line-break-of-span-element)

Answer (score 1):

you can use  tag instead of

tag like

```html
<blockquote>
<span>this is my quote text</span>
<br>
<span>this is my quote text this is my quote text this is my quote text </span>
</blockquote>
```

or you can remove 
 tag from above code
hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is use a tag such as `<span>` rather than the `<p>` tag and give it `white-space:nowrap;`:

```css
span{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<span>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</span>
<span>2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 222 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</span>
</blockquote>
```